# Access to viewbag using javascript code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use aspx c# as a viewengine within ASP.NET mvc project, I want to retrieve value from viewbag using javascript code.

Answer (score 5):

I get all my viewbag related stuff from in a razor view like so ...

```
<script>
  var myJSVariable = @Viewbag.MyViewbagVariable;
</script>
```

You could do the following for the MVC view engine pre-razor I believe

```
<script>
  var myJSVariable = <%Viewbag.MyViewbagVariable%>;
</script>
```

Comment: I use aspx c# as a viewengine

Comment: When I tried the above method, it said "Conditional compilation turned off" and it wouldn't work. I tried looking up for solutions for that and I one of the solutions was Add /*@cc_on @*/ in your code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6655726/620337>
It comments out all the code after it irrespective of where I add it. Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Beware of single quotes in your variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10389766/2550529

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yourVariable= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.yourVariable))
</script>
```

Comment: I use aspx c# as a viewengine

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with something simple like a string, you can save a viewbag in an data-* attribute of a HTML tag and use JavaScript to access that.