# How can a razor for loop be used in a javascript script tag?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The error generated is "Conditional Compilation is turned off".

Conditional Compilation hack from MSDN is prevalent but fails.

There are several questions like this one:
[Conditional Compilation is turned off in Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6655696/1026459)

They all point to the answer of:

```
/*@cc_on @*/
```

From the article seen here at the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y5529x3(v=vs.90).aspx

However, this hack is pretty fail or I seem to fail at implementing it. The trailing `@*` causes the remaining code in the .cshtml file to become commented out. Moreover, `@cc_on` gives an error "cc_on does not exist in the current context".

Here is a piece of code to test in a .cshtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 @for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    document.write(@i);
 }
</script>
```

Which will cause the "Conditional Compilation is turned off" message. Attempting to insert the workaround in there will cause various other messages such as "cc_on" does not exist in the context", "expected ,", or "expected ;", or "expected )" from the for loop.

How can a razor for loop be used in a javascript script tag?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript

Comment: @HatSoft - For the most part it is, although they do not mention the conditional compilation warning which was the aim of this question. Using `@:` and `<text>` work here to generate javascript from razor but the warnings from "conditional compilation" still remain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try surrounding your js with `<text></text>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 @for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    <text>var that = this;</text>
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `@:document.write(@i)` is more succinct, IMO. In other words, use `@:` instead of `<text>` tags.

Comment: Really?  I didn't know about `@:`.

Comment: It's only use is for single line statements where <text> is too verbose. It's functionally equivalent.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman - Although this does compile, the warning still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I need to loop over a model attribute and just serialized it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.items))

    items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item)
    })
</script>
```