# why Razor in jquery not working well

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to call mvc razor element in jquery, but it's not working properly.
Here is an example [image]

Comment: paste the code, cannot see the rest of the code for the `data:` part here

Comment: also read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655696/conditional-compilation-is-turned-off-in-razor) to get rid of that `conditional compilation is turned off` message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try This

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetQuestionBy","Configuration")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {QuestionType:'QuestionId',modelId:'@question.projectmdule.moduleId'}
                success: function (msg) {
                   alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use razor inside double quotes like this `"@question.projectmdule.ProjectmoduleId"`