# Conditional compilation is turned off? Can't assign values from Model. (RequestNumber = @Model.RequestNumber;)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having problems assigning values.

When i debug and the correct values are there but i get an unexpected syntax error?

[image]

I am trying to get values from my model, but the @model is underlined in green with the message conditional compilation is turned off?

```
 $("#btnSubmitYesNon").click(function (e) {
            HideDialogNon();
            e.preventDefault();
            RequestNumber = @Model.RequestNumber;
            ClientName = @Model.ClientName;
            ReasonForValuation = @Model.ReasonForValuation;
            ContactPerson = @Model.ContactPerson;
            ContactNumber = @Model.ContactNumber;
            Relation = @Model.Relation;
            AccountNumber = @Model.AccountNumber;
            BondAmount = @Model.BondAmount;
            PurchasePrice = @Model.PurchasePrice;

            DoNonRegisterdValuation(RequestNumber, ClientName, ReasonForValuation, ContactPerson, ContactNumber, Relation, AccountNumber, BondAmount, PurchasePrice); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the Model properties in quotes:

```
$("#btnSubmitYesNon").click(function (e) {
    HideDialogNon();
    e.preventDefault();
    RequestNumber = '@Model.RequestNumber';
    ClientName = '@Model.ClientName';
    // etc.
});
```

If that also fails, then is this JavaScript part of a Razor view file, or is it external in a .js file?

I've done the quotes approach many times, so that should work (famous last words :) ).