# cshtml Razor Error messages, Conditional Formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, resharper

I'm having a strange issue with my CSHTML files this morning. One moment everything is working fine... then next moment, everything is still working, but all my code highlighting for anything with @ infront of it has gone.
The project still compiles and runs fine, but I'm getting red highlights where ever there is a
Code block.
There are loads of posts for Conditional Formatting on this site, but they all suggest changing the code. I don't want to change any code, it's all working fine. I just want to get the yellow colouring behind the @ back.
It's all working fine in the aspx files. I can't think of what I did to turn this off.

[image]

Edit

I've created a new project and copied every code file over manually.

This is how it looks in the new project.

[image]

And like this in the old

[image]

Comment: I have had this in the past.  Always turned out that there was one line of code on the view that the compiler didn't like.  When I found that line and fixed it the highlighting would come back.

Comment: Yeah, that could be it. I've just deleted everything in each cshtml file, saved and hit compile but it's still there. Could it be something in the aspx files?

Comment: put quotes around '@Html.Raw(Model.CountriesVisited)'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I want that line to be processed by the compiler, not for it to be treated like a string.
It's working fine, it's just the intellisense that seems to think there's a problem somewhere.

Comment: is there a c# code like a `foreach` or `while` loop which encapsulate the above code you have shown? please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655696/conditional-compilation-is-turned-off-in-razor

what exactly do you have in the `Model.CountriesVisited?` an array of `string`?

Comment: It's been a long time since I stopped worrying about those bugs in Visual Studio and hoping that one day Microsoft might actually bring correct Syntax Highligting and Intellisense in Razor views. I just trust my code and know what it does no longer give an F... that there are red squiggles around it.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm not so much looking for a fix for the code, I just want to know what caused it to lose the code highlighting. I've copied the code from the old project to the new file by file, but can't find what it was that messed up the intellisense.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ah, so you're saying it might just be a bug in visual studio, and nothing I've done in my code.

Comment: Oh yeah dude. Terrible bug in VS. Your code is just fine. The fact that it works great when you run it proves that. So cut the crap and stop worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll accept that as a solution! This has been bugging me for days. A pity I can't just delete the suo files or something to get it to reload. Matts first reply had me thinking I'd done something silly in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in Visual Studio. You can't do anything about it. It's just that the dudes at Microsoft didn't get Syntax Highligthing and Intellisense right in Razor views. Hopefully they will in some future version of Visual Studio.

There's nothing wrong with the code you have shown. It works perfectly fine at runtime. Just the tools you are using aren't capable of realizing that.