# How to use a foreach loop with an ILIST<models> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have a razor view  in my MVC 3 application using a `@model IList<TrackerModel>`

`IList<TrackerModel>` is being passed to the view from a action method in my controller.
As the name suggests it's a list of `TrackerModels`.

I want to pass this list the the javascript block at the bottom of my view.

Run the list through a foreach loop so that each model makes use of a certain function.
eg.

```
foreach(var mod in IList<TrackerModel>)
{
     LoadAttachments();
}
```

(I know the above is wrong, but you get the idea)
Can this be done ?

```
   @foreach(var mod in Model)
{
    LoadAttachments(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mod));
}
```

tried the above suggestion , and got the following errors.
@foreach = condition compilation is turned off ?

var = Expected expression ?

in = expected ; ?

LoadAttachments = the name 'LoadAttachments ' does not exist in the current context ?

@Newtonsoft = condition compilation is turned off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take this approach (as opposed to having your javascript call back to a dedicated web service) is you're going to need to render your model into something your javascript can consume, like a json array.

For example in your View

```
 <script>
 @foreach(var mod in Model)
 {
      @:javascriptFunc(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mod));
 }
 </script>
```

This will call your `javascriptFunc` for every item in your `IList<TrackerModel>`.  Each `TrackerModel` is serialized using Newtonsfot.Json, which should be included automatically by Mvc, but if it's not in Mvc 3, you can add it via nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: You'll need to add `@:` before the call to your javascriptFunc.  I forgot that in my original post.  This instructs razor to output the line as plain text.

Comment: Per your conditional compilation, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655696/conditional-compilation-is-turned-off-in-razor, you'll need to add `/*@cc_on @*/` in your code.

Comment: where in the code do I need to add /*@cc_on @*/ ? within script tags.

Comment: I dont think it matters, but I would defer you to the referenced question.  But try adding it at the top of your view after the `@model` statement

Comment: Error'cc_on' does not exist in the current context ?? no matter where I place it ?